# Filtering different data sets so they contain the same values in 2 particular columns

Tags: r, filter, group-by

I am currently working with 3 data sets and will show an example of one below:

Model A

| Fixture | point in time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 week before |
| 1 | 1 day before |
| 2 | 1 week before |
| 3 | 1 week before |
| 3 | 1 hour before |

Dput data from one of the models:

```
structure(list(fixtureId = c("betradar-state-adaptor-25656550", 
"betradar-state-adaptor-25656550", "betradar-state-adaptor-25656550", 
"betradar-state-adaptor-25656550", "betradar-state-adaptor-25656550", 
"betradar-state-adaptor-25656550"), pointInTime = c("ThirtyMinutesBeforeKickoff", 
"AtThirtyMinutes", "FiveMinutesBeforeKickoff", "AtFifteenMinutes", 
"SixHoursBeforeKickoff", "OneHourBeforeKickoff")), row.names = c(12L, 
24L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Unfortunately, this DPUT data only shows data from one fixture.

I am trying to filter all 3 data sets ( I may have to combine them to do this which is fine ), so that we only have the fixtures that are in every model and have the exact same maximum amount of points in time.

so it would look like this for instance:

Model_A: Fixture 1: points in time (1 week, 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute)
Model_B: Fixture 1: points in time (1 week, 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute)
Model _C: Fixture 1: points in time (1 week, 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute)

etc,

I tried to combine them into a new data frame (say df) and use the filter and group by functions as so:

```
df <- rbind(Model_A, Model_B, Model_C)

df <- df %>% group_by(fixtureId) %>% filter(length(pointInTime))
```

However, this doesn't work. If someone could enlighten me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Apologies, its a copy paste error

Comment: What does "have the exact same maximum amount of points in time" mean?  Do you mean that fixture 1 and fixture 2 will be retained if they are in all the models, and they also have the same set of unique points in time?, Same total number of time points?

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% group_by(pointInTime) %>% filter(n_distinct(fixtureId) == 3)`

Comment: Langtang..  its quite hard to explain, basically, there are several different points in time. I am wanting to group all the fixtures that have the exact same time points together, then filter them again for the subset with the largest amount of the same time points if that makes sense?

Comment: are all the time points for a given fixture in a given frame/model unique.. like the 6 time points in the example data are all unique for that fixture?.. Obviously it would help if you could provide a richer example data set via `dput()`